# Rewriting function using dplyr instead of plyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plyr

I do not know why but the following function to draw a ggplot2 work sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I use both dplyr and plyr.

Here is the code

```
data_summary <- function(data, varname, groupnames){
  require(plyr)
  summary_func <- function(x, col){
    c(mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE),
      sd = sd(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))
  }
  data_sum<-ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
                  varname)
  data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean" = varname))
 return(data_sum)
}


library(dplyr)
windowsFonts(Times=windowsFont("Times New Roman"))

df3 <- data_summary(panel_data, varname="invest_amnt", 
                    groupnames=c("trend_id", "stock_name"))

df3$stock_name=as.factor(df3$stock_name)
df3$trend_id=as.factor(df3$trend_id)
head(df3)


df.mean = df3 %>% 
          group_by(stock_name, trend_id) %>% 
        mutate(ymean = mean(invest_amnt))

        df.mean1= df3 %>% 
          group_by(stock_name) %>% 
        mutate(ymean = mean(invest_amnt))

df.mean <- df.mean %>%
mutate( se=sd/sqrt(n))  %>%
  mutate( ic=se * qt((1-0.05)/2 + .5, n-1))

p <- ggplot(df3, aes(x=stock_name, y=invest_amnt, fill=trend_id)) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position=position_dodge()) +
geom_errorbar(data=df.mean, aes(x =stock_name , ymin = ymean - ic, ymax = ymean + ic), width=.2,
                                          position=position_dodge(.9)) 

p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + theme_minimal ()
p + labs(title="", 
         x="Price Path", y = "Invested Amount")+
         ylim(0, 8000)+


geom_errorbar(data= df.mean1, aes(x=stock_name, ymax = ymean, ymin = ymean),
               size=1, linetype = "solid", inherit.aes = F, width = 1) + 
   scale_x_discrete(labels=c("UP\nDOWN", "DOWN\nUP", "STRAIGHT\nGAIN", "STRAIGHT\nLOSS"))+             
               scale_fill_discrete(name = "Trend", labels = c("negative", "flat", "positive")) +

theme_stata() + scale_color_stata()     +

theme(text = element_text(size=12, hjust = 0.5, family="Times"))
```

Sometimes the graph looks exactly like I want it to and then suddenly the second geom_errorbar doesn't show up and I have lots of NAs on my x-axis as labels.

Maybe it would work if I do not use plyr at all?

Comment: You can remove the dependency to `plyr` `data_sum<-ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
                  varname)` with `data %>% group_by(group_names) %>% summarise_at(varname, summary_func)` or specify explicitly the `dplyr::` for functions that are common

Comment: Might it be that you have namespace conflicts when both plyr and dplyr are loaded? Does it help if you specify the package name in front of the relevant functions? (e.g. `plyr::mutate` or `dplyr::mutate`)

Comment: @akrun I did that. Seems like the fault isnt a conflict between dplyr and plyr as the problem is the still there.

Comment: have you removed the `require(plyr)` in the code.  Anyway, it is not easier to debug without a reproducible example

Comment: @akrun Yes, i removed it. I will try to make a reproducible sample later. It will take some time